# Django serializer validate not firing

Tags: python, django

I have a choices field on a Django model as such:

```
VALID = 0
INVALID = 1
FLANGGED = 2
NOT_REVIEWED = 3

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (VALID, 'Valid'),
    (INVALID, 'Invalid'),
    (FLANGGED, 'Flagged'),
    (NOT_REVIEWED, 'Not Reviewed'),
)

review_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=NOT_REVIEWED)
```

When I surface this to the front-end I use `obj.get_review_status_display()` to get the String value.

When I'm editing this model (via DRF), and I pass the integer value, I can see my `validate()` method on my serializer is getting called. However, when I pass the string value to patch the model, the `validate()` never gets called:

```
def validate(self, data):
    valid_status_key = False
    if 'review_status' in data:
        for k, v in Application.STATUS_CHOICES:
            if v == data['review_status']:
                valid_status_key = k

        if not valid_status_key:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid review status')
        else:
            data['review_status'] = valid_status_key

    # only called when data['review_statuse'] is an Int, not String
    assert False, [data, valid_status_key]

    return data
```

So... How can I pass the String value to the backend, and hit the `validate()` method to validate it against my Choices field?